# WindowsUpdateLog update-id based drivers unavailable from Microsoft Update Catalog

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, cataloging

For all `Device Drivers`, the `WindowsUpdate` stores the `Driver Title` along with its unique `update-id` in the path `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log`. In recent versions of windows (8 and above), this log is being generated by the power shell command `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`.

A sample WindowsUpdate.log Driver Title and its update-id from my system is below

```
2023-12-02 17:15:11.5213155 148   8072  Agent             Title = Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Display - 31.0.12027.9001
2023-12-02 17:15:11.5213175 148   8072  Agent             UpdateId = 96941A83-1B8F-430C-96A5-9522B8586A19.1
```

The [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) website offers search based on update-id as through the following link

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=2ACA9060-0321-4F44-B15D-EBBD911A6295

So, to download device driver packages, to be used for later use, i used to go to C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log (Generated by Get-WindowsUpdateLog during recent times) and watch for driver titles and their update ids below. Then i used to search for the driver page in microsoft update catalog and download precisely that particular driver.

Say, for example, for the following title in `WindowsUpdate.log`

```
2023-12-02 17:15:11.5213155 148   8072  Agent             Title = Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Display - 31.0.12027.9001
2023-12-02 17:15:11.5213175 148   8072  Agent             UpdateId = 96941A83-1B8F-430C-96A5-9522B8586A19.1
```

the relevant search webpage link for microsoft update catalog used to be

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=96941A83-1B8F-430C-96A5-9522B8586A19

But, when i open this link, the website says update requested could not be found.

And if I search Microsoft Update Catalog website with the driver title, none of the results include the update id shown by the WindowsUpdate.log

Example:

for the above listed title `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Display - 31.0.12027.9001`, the search

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Advanced%20Micro%20Devices%2C%20Inc.%20-%20Display%20-%2031.0.12027.9001

gives three results, but none of them include the specific update-id (`96941A83-1B8F-430C-96A5-9522B8586A19`) shown from WindowsUpdate.log

[Driver Title Search Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3nu4.png) (sorry, can't post images)

So, How to download precisely these specific `update-id` based driver packages, that WindowsUpdate downloads, to be used for further clean installations of the same OS?

Answer (score 1):

That driver shows up at `https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=AMD%20radeon%20display%20driver`, along with other AMD drivers:

[image: Finding AMD Driver]

Or just enter the driver ID: `https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=31.0.12027.9001`. Simply enter the ID in the Search box.

The internet changes; keeping an old link may not work. As Heraclitus stated, ""δὶς ἐς τὸν αὐτὸν ποταμὸν οὐκ ἂν ἐμβαίης," i.e., "Your browser cannot intercept the same stream twice."

Comment: updated question to better mention the issue. the exact updateid of the driver shown from windowsupdate log is not available in microsoft update catalog.

Comment: Likely the *exact* update with GUID {96941A83-1B8F-430C-96A5-9522B8586A19} has been pulled (e.g., due to issues) or *it has been assigned a new GUID*. In fact , a web search for *just* that GUID found only your question! So search on the **update** ID, 31.0.12027.9001.

Comment: Its only been a couple of days, since i freshly installed windows and did this. If it is pulled it must be many days ago. So, is it possible for pulled update guid to be displayed in windowsupdatelog ? If its assigned/superseded with a new GUID, how would i find the new GUID ?

Comment: With the above example, there are only 3 results, and its easy to try them. But, the issue happens with many other drivers too. With some drivers, whose titles are very generic, there are like hundred plus results, and manually downloading the correct compatible driver could be very hard.